# How can I do a hover effect for my social icons in css?

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to create a simple hover effect, I have a gray Facebook, Twitter and YouTube image and when it gets hover I want to get the original color from the social media, that's all I want.

This is my HTML:

```html
<div class="social-top">
    
    <ul>
        <li><a href=""><img src="images/social/fb.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="images/social/twitter.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="images/social/yt.png"></a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```css
.social-top {
    width: 150px;
    padding-left: 650px;
}

.social-top li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
}

.social-top a {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
}

.social-top a:hover {
    top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Do u use chrome? press F12 and follow it, look how the image is made.. http://lalomacd.com.mx/2013/wp-content/themes/laloma-theme-second/images/tube-icon.png I found it with the css of the site, it's an image with a transprent background

Comment: http://lalomacd.com.mx/2013/wp-content/themes/laloma-theme-second/images/twitter-icon.png etc...

Answer (score 2):

This is how you do it. You can place a transparent PNG in here for your links, instead of the text, if you want. Or you can check out using some font icon libraries, that use text to create a social media icon for you. For example, check out Fontello. http://fontello.com/

Here is the code I wrote for your effect:

```
    <div class="social-top">

    <ul>
        <li class="facebook"><a href="#self">F</a></li>
            <li class="twitter"><a href="#self">T</a></li>
                <li class="youtube"><a href="#self">YT</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>



.social-top {
   float: right;
 }

.social-top li {

display: inline-block;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
background-color: #ccc;
border-radius: 150px;
}

.social-top li.facebook:hover {
background-color: #006;

}

.social-top li.twitter:hover {
   background-color: #060;

}

 .social-top li.youtube:hover {
  background-color: #600;

 }

.social-top li:hover a {
       color: #fff;
}

.social-top a {
 display: block;
   line-height: 40px;
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
```

Here's the link to js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eNU8H/

Answer (score 1):

According to the site you supplied, they just made an image with the 2 wanted images.

And in the hover they just change the back-ground position.

Example:

```
.srss{
         background-image:url(images/rss-icon.png);
         background-position:bottom;
 }

 .srss:hover{
    background-position:top;
 }
```

With an HTML according to this:

Using an image like [this one](http://lalomacd.com.mx/2013/wp-content/themes/laloma-theme-second/images/rss-icon.png)

```
  <a href="http://lalomacd.com.mx/2013/feed/" target="blank"><img class="srss" src="http://lalomacd.com.mx/2013/wp-content/themes/laloma-theme-second/images/blank.png" alt=""></a>
```

All of this you can get it directly form the site viewing the source and the css

Of course this is not the only way, you can change the background image instead of the background-position, but all of that is according of the way you like it the most

Answer (score 0):

instead of using img tags create div tags and set their background image to the social icons and on hover change them

Answer (score 0):

They are just using image sprites. Set the background-image to the path to the sprite. In normal view, set the background-position to see the dark icon. On hover state, change the background position to the part of the sprite with the colored icon.